# Get Customer Name for Coupon Codes in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have searched on the net and on this site for a solution but couldn't find any.
I would like to get the customer name associated to a coupon code in Magento. I found some code for the times the coupon code was used but I couldn't get the customer name.

I tried the following code:

```
<?php

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

umask(0);
Mage::app( 'admin' );

$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon/usage');
$coupon->load('dd_38WX9N', 'code');
if($coupon->getId()) {
    $timesUsed = $coupon->getTimesUsed();
    $customer = $coupon->getCustomerId();
    echo $timesUsed;
    echo $customer;
}

?>
```

Could someone please help me with that and point me to the right direction.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Daniel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the good solution. you need to use the resource and not the model to get access to the table salesrule_coupon_usage and get the customer_id list

```
/*@var $coupon Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon */
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
$coupon->load('dd_38WX9N', 'code');

if($coupon->getId()){
    /* @var $resourceCouponUsage Mage_SalesRule_Model_Mysql4_Coupon_Usage */
    $resourceCouponUsage = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_usage');
    $read = $resourceCouponUsage->getReadConnection();
    $select = $read->select()
                ->from($resourceCouponUsage->getMainTable())
                ->where('coupon_id = ?', $coupon->getId());

    $data = $read->fetchAll($select);
    print_r($data);
    foreach($data as $couponUsage){
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($couponUsage['customer_id']);
        echo $customer->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Diglin for your help. That worked like a charm. You just saved my day :-)

Comment: I tried to do that, but my reputation doesn't allow me to vote :-( I'll come back and do that as soon as my reputation allows me to vote.

Answer (score 2):

When you are able to get the ID of the customer, you also can get the whole customer object:

```
$customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
print_r($customer_data);
```

There you can get the name as well.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the customer ID. I need to get the customer ID associated to a coupon code. For example the coupon code "xyz" has been used and now I would like the get the ID or name from the customer who used that coupon code. In Magento Coupon Code report you can only see that this coupon has been used but you can't see who used that specific coupon.